# DlgDirListComboBox in C#/VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, api

I have a project where I want to display a combo to show dropdown list of directory listing like dialog boxes does.

there is a Win32 API

```
int DlgDirListComboBox(
   LPTSTR lpPathSpec,
   int nIDComboBox,
   int nIDStaticPath,
   UINT nFileType 
);
```

and its c# version (thanks to [pInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/DlgDirListComboBox.html))

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int DlgDirListComboBox(IntPtr hDlg, StringBuilder lpPathSpec,
   int nIDComboBox, int nIDStaticPath, uint uFiletype);
```

but I can't figure out what value should I pass in for `nIDComboBox` parameter (I tried and `handle` do not work here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nIDComboBox` should be the Win32 Control ID of the combobox. You can get it with another P/Invoke call by passing the control's `Handle`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetDlgCtrlID(IntPtr hWnd);
```

But you can also list the directories without resorting to P/Invoke by using `Directory.GetDirectories`